# Java Reflection: Creating class instance dynamically and assigning it to Parent object

Tags: java, reflection

```
String child = "C";
Parent p = null;
try {
    Class c1 = new Class.forName(child);
    Constructor co = c1.getConstructor();
    // p=co.newInstance(null); //This gives compilatoin error cannot
    // conver object to Parent
    // p=(c1.getClass())co.newInstance(null);//also gives cast errror
    p = (Parent) co.newInstance(null);// this works but it typecasts the
    // child to Parent
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

What am i trying to do.

I have multiple Child classes inherited from Parent. I am getting child class name as string input.

I want to instantiate the object of Child class and assign it to Parent. I do not want to type cast Child to Parent. As later in the code i need to compare two Child classes. If I typecast it to Parent. I cannot differentiate between Child1 and Child2.

Comment: How do you compare your child1 and child2?

Comment: You might want to check out [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typecasting has **absolutely no effect** on the object itself.  Using `p = (Parent) t` simply does a runtime check on `t` to make sure that the type of `t` is assignable to `Parent` (i.e. either `t` is-a `Parent` or it is-a subclass of `Parent`) .  Afterward, `t` will still be a `Child1` or whatever its *actual* type always has been.

Use the explicit cast.

Comment: What if we want to use methods of child class in this scenario? How to get reference variable of child class?

Comment: @zookastos: If an instance of the child class is what you need, that's what you should cast to.  If you only care that it's *some* child of a certain parent, cast it to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like:

```
Object parent = null;
String child = String.class.getName();  //not necessary, can just use String.class directly
Class childClass = Class.forName(child);
Class parentClass = Object.class;

if (parentClass.isAssignableFrom(childClass)) {
    parent = childClass.newInstance();
}

System.out.println("Parent is:  " + parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even the Parent is cast form the 2 different children as

```
Parent parent1 = (Parent)child1;
Parent parent2 = (Parent)child2;
```

The parent1 and parent2 are totally different based on each child.

You may see the difference by printing them as

```
System.out.println(parent1.getClass().getName());
System.out.println(parent2.getClass().getName());
```

Then you may compare it by using the getName() as well.

I hope this may help to achieve the requirement.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.