# Identify classes at run-time

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm working in a project for Android using libGDX framework in which I show some examples of the use of three graphic libraries. Once started, the app must show a menu with a link for each sample, its title and a little description. For the time being, I'm creating all manually, declaring a new link for each sample, but as I will have a lot of samples and I'll add new ones in each app version, I would like to identify them and generate a new entry automatically.

The samples part is composed of an abstract class called `Sample` and a class for each sample that extends from `Sample`. How could I accomplish this? The requisites will be to have the possibility to identify all samples at run-time and get information about them (name, description, etc.) without the need of create an instance previously.

My actual options are use Annotations (don't know if it is possible or if I need an external library to search for this annotations at run-time) or use something like a JSON file. What do you think is the best way (I'm open to other solutions of course) to solve this problem?

Comment: Is this not a classic polymorphism case?

Comment: I think You can use something like the visitor design pattern http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-visitor

Comment: You can also obtain the class in runtime by using the method getClass() implemented on the class Object (that is extended by all objects) but in this case i'm not sure if it will return the real class or the class Sample. I think it's better to use a visitor

Comment: dont use the `getClass()` to check what class it is. Instead you use the `instanceof` to check what class it is.

Comment: @user3198050 I have to use a visitor patter without doubt, but I don't see where I could store samples data (name, description, etc.) to get it while I create menu entries. Nor do I see how could I obtain the list of available samples. Could you give me a example?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://steigert.blogspot.de/2012/02/2-libgdx-tutorial-game-screens.html This does what you are looking for i think. Well this is for screens but i think you can just adapt it to whatever you need. The abstract does hold what every Sample need and the implementation extends them by the Implementation spec code.

Comment: @BennX Thanks, but I think that I haven't explained well my problem. The most important part of this is to identify all available tests at run-time and to obtain its data (name, description, etc.) without the need of create an instance of them.

Comment: Please specify your question to what you are looking for. IF you are looking for a from text/json/xml/whatever to Sample parsing so add this as question. If you are familier with json use json files to define them. If not use something like a structured text for example xml. Both can easy be parsed in libgdx and easy be iterated and checked what it is

Comment: That is actually the third paragraph of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend using XML  and take the class you want to create as Tag so something like this:

```
<root>
     <sampleimplement1 name ="sampleimplement1" descript="sample1 description" ..... more attributes here... />
     <sampleimplement2 name ="sampleimplement2" descript="sample2 description" ..... more attributes here... />
     <sampleimplement3 name ="sampleimplement3" descript="sample3 description" ..... more attributes here... />
</root>
```

This can now be parsed with the `XmlReader` of libgdx to a `Element`. So the element is not the root.
Last but not least you can iterate over the childs of the `root` and check what the name of the Tag is. Depending on the name you create a different implementation of your `Sample`.

```
XmlReader r = new XmlReader();
Element e = r.parse(xml);//<--- the XML as string also possible as file
for (int i = 0; i < e.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        Element child = e.getChild(i);
        switch(child.getName()){
            case "sampleimplement1":
            //create sample1
            break;
....
....
    }
```

Comment: As I said in reply to your comment, this is not exactly the problem. What I need is to identify (detect on the go) all available samples without the need to instantiate them before. I also need to obtain its data (name, description, etc.). I don't see how to achieve any of this with this proposed solution. Also, I don't use Scene2D for my samples so I have no Actors or a Stage to iterate.

Comment: What is a test? And you cant check anything in java without having an Object of it. To optain the data you cast it to the right Class and use the methods of the class. 

So you are looking for something like an xml or json parsing? You write for example `<Monster name="test" level="5"/>` and parse it into an entity? Please concrete your question that what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: I mean samples, sorry. And yes, you can do it. For exmple, libGDX uses this class https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/utils/GdxTests.java. I can't use it because I need more data (as I said, name, description, etc.).

Comment: No as you can see there is an instance of the txt which get iterated. so no this is not without an Object. Sorry i dont get your question. Delete

Comment: Yes, but I mean that you don't have an instance of each sample.

Comment: changed the answer to a possible solution. Its java 7 based else you need to create a kind of enum with the possible names and use the `enum.valueOf(e.getName())` If you want it more dynamic you need to create a document where all allowed classes are contained and check the `e.getName()` against the allowed classes. Maybe use Java reflections to get the right constructor just by the name of the class. But this does have a bad performance! Moreover with this solution you can fast write an editor for it with java Swing and jdom2.

Comment: Yep, more like this. The only problem here is that I don't want a switch case. I would like to be able to edit that file and... yeah, thats all. Is it possible to create an instance of a sample with only its class name defined in the file?

Comment: Yes thats possible with java reflections but it has a really bad runtime. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619930/java-reflection-creating-class-instance-dynamically-and-assigning-it-to-parent
But you are using different implementations of sample i think. I would than recommend to change the Sample to be componend based. So everything is a sample but can have different componens. Just store them as HashMap<String, String> and you can dynamically load everything you whish to the Sample and store it inside of the "componentmap". So sample is a kind of tree of components and attributes.

Comment: You then can add the attributes as childs to the xml-Tag of the sample or even compleat componens with methods. same as shown above. get the Element of the Sample and iterate over the Childs (which would be the attributes and components) and add them to the sample.